# win10/nvidia: how to force a full-screen game to use native resolution?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

There are some old games that use low resolution in full screen. Modes other than the native, default resolution don't look good on my monitor (which complains about it).
How do I force that native resolution (1920x1080) would always be used, employing scaling, mapping, or whatever is necessary?

I have win10 with an nvidia geforce card.

Comment: It would be good to put a name of a game you are having trouble with.  Ideally there is a setting within the game that allows you to change the display resolution.  If not Windows 10 has the ability for some compatibility if you right click and go to properties -> compatibility tab on the .exe

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, if I couldn't find it, then there probably isn't such an option, or otherwise it happens often enough--it's not a single game--that I don't want to start searching and asking about a non-existent setting each time. I'm familiar with win10 compatibility, and it doesn't enforce resolution.

Comment: Check [Widescreen Gaming Forum](https://www.wsgf.org/). The short summary is that there is no way to force the resolution in any way unless it is (in whatever way) supported by the game.

Comment: I suspected as much, and it's weird that it isn't implemented in the graphics card or OS level.